# How to Generate an executable solution for a MAVEN TESTNG Selenium-Webdriver framework

Tags: maven, selenium, teamcity, pom.xml

I'm using testNG and Selenium to run multiple functionals test of my application.
after doing mvn install the project builds successfully and generate the target file that contains all the classes and the .jar file but this solution is not executable since my framework does not contains a main method since is a TESTNG FRAMEWORK.

How can this file be executable in order to be able to deploy it to the lower environments or run the solution using task scheduler !

this is for a test automation framework for a web application using maven testng and selenium webdriver(PageObjectModel)

C:\Users\myuser\Documents\test\myapp\target>java -jar myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

no main manifest attribute, in myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

this is when I get when trying to execute the jar from the target file generated.

Comment: You can use maven execution goal to run your test

Comment: Yes I can but in order to deploy to the lower environments I need an executable solution in this case Target File

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reconsidering your approach and instead of running a executable .jar you should [run `testng.jar` like](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng):

```
java org.testng.TestNG /path/to/your/testng.xml
```

You can create a helper class which will have [`public static void main()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) declaration like:

```
package com.example;

import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setTestClasses(new Class[]{TestClass.class}); // replace TestClass with your actual class where your test methods live
        testNG.run();
    }
}
```

Then add the next entry to you *pom.xml* file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                       <Main-Class>com.example.TestRunner</Main-Class>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Once you package your app you will see `myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar` which will be an executable.

More information:

- [TestNG](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG)
- [Running TestNG programmatically](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but is not working the main method find the tests but it skip them for some reason ===============================================
TEST Automation Script QA
Total tests run: 77, Failures: 0, Skips: 77
Configuration Failures: 16, Skips: 370
===============================================